# C programming fucntion no argument return printf statement

Tags: c, function, arguments

I am trying to use a function that has no arguments and all it does is spit out a printf statement, but I don't know how to do so, or if I am even calling this function correctly. Here is an example of what I have.

```
void list();
char L;

int main()
{
    L = list();
    printf("%c, L);
    void list()
    {
        printf("f - find a quote\ny - find a year\nq - quit");
    }
}
```

any suggestions? **Note: I can't use a break statement or flag**

Comment: do you know what `list()` returns?

Comment: What problem are you having? I can see at least three compiler errors that this will produce, so if you are unsure about the meaning of them, please include them in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'spit out a printf statement'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to attempt to store the return value of your `list` function, as it returns void. Simply calling the function will cause it to be executed, and run your printf.

Here's what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void list();
int main() {
    list();
    return 0;
}
void list() {
     printf("f - find a quote\ny - find a year\nq - quit");
}
```

Comment: probably needs a `\n` at the end of the printf

Answer (score 1):

If you just call your function `list` within the main function, it will execute the code within `list`.

It'd look like

```
void list();
int main() {
    list();
    return(0);
}    
void list() {
    printf("f - find a quote\ny - find a year\nq - quit");
}
```